# PHP DocuSign API - Create a non-required field

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using the PHP library provided by DocuSign within my application.

I would like to know how to create a text field that is NOT required to be filled in by the user.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing.

```
$text = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();
$text->setAnchorString("Name");
$text->setAnchorXOffset("100");
$text->setAnchorYOffset("-20");
$text->setTabLabel("Name");
$text->setName("Name");
$text_tabs[] = $text;

$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setTextTabs($text_tabs);
```

I want this field to be optional but it's always required when trying to complete the signing process.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to set the **optional** property of the text tab to **true**.

```
$text->setOptional("true");
```

(8/17/16: Updated answer to reference the **optional** property -- instead of the **required** property.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kim. There doesn't seem to be a setRequired method in the SignHere class. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting -- it looks like the **SignHere** tab doesn't have a property named "**required**" like other tabs do.  Instead, it has a property named "**optional**" -- you'll want to set this property to **true**.  I've updated my answer with this info; if it solves your problem please mark as accepted so that others may benefit from it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: That look like exactly what I'm looking for! You have been very helpful. Thank you very much!